# MYSQL Datetime as varchar and how to display year only

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have this Application where Releasedates of Musicalbums are saved into the MySQL Database as `Varchar` (I have no influence on that) so it displays the date like **(2014-09-11)**. How can I make it that the Releasedate gets displayed like only **(2014)** ? Do I have to convert it to `DATETIME`

My MySQl query looks like this:

```
    SELECT products.pro_id, 
           products.title AS album_title, 
           products.genre AS album_genre, 
           products.coverarttoenailurl AS cover_image, 
           products.ccws_pro_id AS product_upc, 
           track_title, 
           track_duration,  
           album_id, 
           physicalReleaseDate, 
           digitalReleaseDate 
   FROM products 
   INNER JOIN track_albumn_information 
   ON products.ccws_pro_upc = track_albumn_information.product_upc 
   AND track_albumn_information.artist_id ='".$artist_id."' 
   ORDER BY physicalReleaseDate, digitalReleaseDate DESC
```

the relevant Fields are `physicalReleaseDate` and `digitalReleaseDate`

Please help anyone...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SUBSTR(physicalReleaseDate, 1, 4)
SUBSTR(digitalReleaseDate, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This...Use Year function of mysql for ref. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year

```
SELECT products.pro_id,products.title AS album_title, products.genre AS album_genre, products.coverarttoenailurl AS cover_image, products.ccws_pro_id 
                AS product_upc, track_title, track_duration, album_id, Year(physicalReleaseDate) , year(digitalReleaseDate) FROM products INNER JOIN track_albumn_information 
                ON products.ccws_pro_upc = track_albumn_information.product_upc AND track_albumn_information.artist_id ='".$artist_id."' ORDER BY physicalReleaseDate, digitalReleaseDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is varchar column you use use LEFT function

```
LEFT(physicalReleaseDate,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LEFT() which returns a specified number of chars from the left hand side of the string i.e.

```
LEFT(digitalReleaseDate,4)
```

[For reference.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

Answer (score 0):

```
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(datecolumn,'%Y-%m-%d'))
```